Cryptography self-evaluation: how ARE you doing?
There are lots of metrics we can use to "measure" a site, and we do, but none of them matter as much as having a healthy and happy site full of interesting questions and expert answers.
So, let's talk about site health. Specifically, your site health.
Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from Cryptography Stack Exchange. Review them and take a look around the Internet as if you were trying to find answers to them. Are they interesting questions? Are the answers we have better than what Google has to offer? Are they easily found?
Upvote the corresponding post in this "thread" when our answer is better. Downvote when Google wins. If we're kinda on par with Google, just use common sense and your expertise to guide your vote. :)
Comment to let us know your thoughts... and if you need help, use our handy dandy guide.
(This evaluation will close on May 4, 2012.)

"Are the answers we have better than what Google has to offer?"  That's another way of saying, "Are our answers the best in the world?"

How does the MOV attack work?
Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

I found little by way of non-academic explanations. These notes seem to be the best contender with this answer. I think CE wins.

What are the advantages of a static ECDH key?
Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

I did find RFC 5753, but this actually only mentions an advantage of static-ephemeral relative to static-static, not relative to ephemeral-ephemeral (which does not apply there). So again, no other sites found :-/

Can I secure my key by XORing it with a hashed password?
Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

We are the first Google result for the title... and the second and the third. And the fourth is SO. Despite this being (a close variant of) an FAQ, none of the other first page Google results for this title look useful at all. So, yeah, I'd say we win this round.

synchronization of counters in HOTP
Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

So I find a patent application from 2009 about HOTP, which simply copies the RFC from 2005?

Can we use elliptic curve cryptography in wireless sensors?
Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Maybe my Google-Foo is weak, but I don't find much here, apart from several research papers. Our responses are quite good, given the weak question.

Are derived hashes weakening the root?
Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Again, my Google-Foo fails here :-( ... though the question could have worded better, I think we have quite reasonable answers. Some of the discussion in the comments could be condensed into the answers themselves, though.

@PaŭloEbermann the question is the first hit for me with "related hashes" (or "derived hashes").

@Gilles When I said my Google-Foo fails, I meant I had no success finding other resources about this by Google.

Any techniques for evading frequency based crypt analysis without encrypting?
Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

This is simply a bad question.

The question does not make sense.  The person who asked it doesn't know exactly what they want but the answers actually are fairly nice.

How to construct a zero-knowledge proof of a number of the form $n=p^a q^b$
Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

This is a quite special question (likely a homework one), and I didn't find anything with Google. On the other hand, our answer has only some "hints" (which I don't fully understand) and a bit of discussion in the comments - this could be expanded.

How can one share information using the 'host-proof' paradigm?
Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

The question is not the best, but our answer doesn't tell much more. There is some discussion in the comments which could get made into a proper answer. Google host-proof paradigm finds some more pages with better information (though that could be said to be off-topic here).

@PaŭloEbermann Even the SO answer is better. Close here?

Standardized parameters for elliptic curve cryptography
Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Our answer contains only links, and the same ones as Wikipedia. But it is not clear what more could be said for this question - maybe Thomas' comment could be incorporated into the answer?

We're clearly worse than http://infosecurity.ch/20100926/not-every-elliptic-curve-is-the-same-trough-on-ecc-security , but I didn't check how easy that page is to find.
